# Custom form in Zend 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have created new class which extends Zend_Form, but when I´m trying to iterate through all Elements in my new custom form (or only count them all) the result is always 0.

```
class Application_Form_ZendForm extends Poroform_Form {
    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->setAttrib('id', 'contact-form');

        $this->addElement('text', 'textt', array(
            'label' => 'Foo',
            'value' => 'test',
            "attribs" => array(
                "icon" => "icon-append fa fa-user",
                "section" => "col col-6"
            ),
        ));
    }
}


class Poroform_Form extends Zend_Form {

    public function __construct($options = null) {
        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    public function init() {
        $this->setAttrib("class", "smart-form");
        $this->setAttrib("novalidate", "novalidate");
        $this->setAttrib("elem_count", count($this->getElements())); //why is result 0?

        $this->addElementPrefixPath('Poroform_Form_Decorator_', '/Poroform/Form/Decorator/', 'decorator');
        $this->setElementDecorators(Array('SmartadminInput'));

        foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) { //not working
                $element->setAttrib("test", "aaa"); 
        }
    }
}
```

So Am I looking for custom forms by wrong side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `parent::init()` in `Poroform_Form::init()` before you iterate over the form elements.

If you follow the flow, you'll see that in `Poroform_form::init()` at the point at which you are iterating over the form elements, you truly have not yet added any. All the elements are added in the parent `Application_Form_ZendForm`.

Comment: Thx for replay David. Adding `parent::init()` at the begining of `Poroform_Form::init()` didn´t solve the problem. Actually I solved it by adding `$this->init();` at the start of `Poroform_Form::__construct()`.